# is it possible to remove attribute from website with Imacros

Tags: imacros

I need to remove from input attribute with name `readonly="readonly`", is it possible to do it with Imacros?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SET myInputId "inputid"
URL GOTO=javascript:{document.getElementById('{{myInputId}}').removeAttribute('readonly');}
```